# How to use AWS profile with Amplify?

Tags: aws-amplify

Amplify does not support CLI option `--profile`. It always uses profile specified when application was generated. Different team members use different AWS profiles.
How to change/configure/use profile different than profile used during application generation?
Aim is to publish changes from different computer. Final goal is to use CI server to publish application to different regions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amplify does not work like "other" development tools where tool is detached from git. Amplify goes hand in hand with Git and requires initialization after cloning. Running `amplify init` and choosing existing environment (which is pushed by other developer), it is possible to select different AWS profile.

Answer (score 0):

There are many changes made over the year, my best bet would be for you to go through this [link](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/usage/headless/) to achieve your final goal. As per the document you can mention the profile name as a parameter.

`profileName: The name of the profile if useProfile is set to true. accessKeyId: The aws access key id if useProfile is set to false. secretAccessKey: The aws secret access key if useProfile is set to false. region: The aws region if useProfile is set to false.`